# PCF8574a not responding - TWI

Tags: c, arduino, embedded, microcontroller

I am trying to control a 7 digit display with a PCF8574a port expander, but it's not working, and I am clueless now.

I want to control the 7 digit display with an Arduino and I've wired it up like so (ignore the button, and there is a mistake in the drawing with the three bottom right wires, they are connected to ground):
[image]

Looking at the [datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/PCF8574_PCF8574A.pdf), the TWI address is `0x38`. What I want at first is just turning all the LED's off in the 7 segment display. So this is my code:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <Wire.h>

#define PCF8574A_TWI_Address 0x38

int main()
{
    Wire.begin();

    uint8_t test = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        Wire.beginTransmission(PCF8574A_TWI_Address);
        Wire.write(test);
        Wire.endTransmission();
    }
}
```

But this is not working. Nothing happens. What could be the issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because handling the problem in a useful manner requires access to hardware.

Comment: In some 99% of all faulty breadboard circuits, the fault is caused by the breadboard itself. A cheap solder iron and some experiment boards will save you lots and lots of time.

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope to watch the signals?

Comment: why do you upload a drawing and explain which mistakes you did in the drawing. just upload a corrected one to avoid unnecessary confusion. did you check all connections for continuity?

Comment: and what do you expect to happen if you simply send 0 to the device?

Comment: @Piglet I expect all the LEDs to turn off on the 7 digit display.

Comment: @Ludin hmmmmm okay. While I don't have some experiment boards on hand I can try another breadboard.

Comment: @thebusybee Nope :/

Comment: @MartinJames so you are saying this is more of a hardware issue instead of a software issue? At this point I don't know if it either or both.

Comment: @Lundin So, I've tried that. Issue remains.

Comment: *Well, it gets difficult but not impossible without good laboratory equipment. ;-) If you plan to make more in that field think about at least some simple hobbyist's devices.* Anyway, you could try to shift the address 1 bit down, as [Wire Library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Wire) documents. If this doesn't help, write a loop that tries all addresses. Some are reserved, but this is just a test. If one works, you only have to identify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved now. There wasn't just one issue, it was a bunch of them. First and foremost was the portexpender faulty. However changing it out did not solve the problem. As @Lundin already suggested, my was breadboard faulty as well. After soldering it, it still didn't work. I forgot to add pull-up resistors to the SDA and SLC pins. After doing that, everything worked as expected.